# ONLY when room is cold -- Monitor LCD screen flashing on/off when first turning on

Tags: display, hardware-failure, lcd

So here's the situation : I have an old Samsung SyncMaster 932bf. Manufactured in 2007, I've been using it everyday since. So yeah, I'm aware the monitor is very old and probably just needs to be changed. But it still works for now -- I'm not replacing it until it completely fails.

I'm not a tech guy. I'm simply curious if someone experienced knows the cause of this problem.

I did a research and most answers to similar questions suggest a bad capacitor. However, I found zero question with this twist : the problem only occurs when the room is cold. By cold I mean under 20C (68 fahrenheit). It **never** happened when the ambient temperature is higher than that. Note that it doesn't get too cold. I don't let temperature go under 16C (60 fahrenheit) in that room. Which is well within operating temperature stated in the manual (10 °C ~ 40 °C or 50 °F ~ 104 °F).

The problem : when turning ON the monitor and the room is cold, the screen will shortly turn ON then turn back off. The monitor power light stays ON, however. I simply turn it back off, wait a few seconds and then turn the monitor ON again. It may work the second time around or take up to 4-5 tries before the screen turns ON **and** stays ON.

Once the screen is ON, there is no problem whatsoever. No flickering. Great colors and image quality.

What I tried : disconnect both power & VGA cables. Reconnect everything, making sure the connections are firmly in place. I also connected the monitor to another PC, same exact issue.

This is not a major issue for an old monitor. I expect it to die completely at any moment. But this issue started **years** ago and the screen still works. Furthermore, I'm curious because of the temperature twist. What I've read so far always seem to indicate that, when it's faulty capacitor(s), the display either work or it doesn't. It either turns ON or it does not.

Other note : at first, it started very briefly flashing when powering ON the screen. Now, the only difference is it stays ON longer. Then the screen turns black usually after about 1 minute.

Any idea of the cause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cause is a part (like a capacitor or a resistor) that is open when cool and does not connect until warm.

An equally likely cause is a cold solder joint that does not connect until the Monitor gets warm and the joint expands to connect.  I have seen this in electronic equipment.

Both causes above may be present in your monitor.